# onBackPressed() is not getting called in any activity in my android project. While in my other projects it works

Tags: java, android

As I am overriding `onBackPressed()` method in multiple activities of my Android project but it is not getting called, and my block of code is like below:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    //my logics;
}
```

But this block is not getting visited on back press and it goes to previous activity.

I have searched and found people work with `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown`, which I don't want to use because in my other projects I am using `onBackPressed()` , where target sdk versions all are same, and there it works fine.

What should I do to get this done?, Please help me to figure out this problem.

Comment: Has the app that `onBackPressed` isn't called in [opted in to the predictive back gesture](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back/predictive-back-gesture#opt-predictive) via `android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? You should be following the [Provide custom back navigation guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back) rather than putting any code in `onBackPressed` at all.

Comment: Hey @ianhanniballake , I am doing the same thing in `AndroidManifest.xml` with this project as I did in other projects too. I am not using `android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"`. I tried after seeing this but that too doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do you use different Android versions? Android code is not always backwards compatible between different API versions.

Comment: What is the target SDK version?.

Comment: I think the onBackPressed() is deprecated now.

can you try something like this:

onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
               // your code
            }
        })

Comment: @dev.bmax the target SDK version is 32

Comment: @Chandresh204 It works in my other project irrespective of it gets deprecated.

Comment: How do you know it isn't being called? Have you set a breakpoint or added logging?

Answer (score 2):

`on onBackPressed()` is deprecated for higher android versions.

Instead try using the onBackPressedDispatcher.
Add a call back when the activity/ fragment is created and don't forget to pass the lifercycle owner otherwise the callback won't be called, and remove it when the activity/ fragment is destroyed.
Kotlin example code:

```
onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(owner = yourActivityOrFragment) {
    ... // your code
    finish()
}
```

Comment: OnBackPressed is deprecated, but it must be called, if there is no enabled callback added to the onBackPressedDispatcher, so I assume that there is already knew defined, and that's why deprecated onBackPressed fun is not being called

Comment: @sunny could you provide the whole class of your activity, where the onBackPressed is not called?

Answer (score 0):

Though it's difficult to answer without looking at the high level app structure but I will still try.

1. **Fragments** - If you are overriding `onBackPressed()` within the fragments that are hosted by your activity and not calling `super.onBackPressed()` or the way your fragments handle `onBackPressed()` can cause this issue.
2. **Super** - Make sure you are calling `super.onBackPressed()` in all the overridden `onBackPressed()` methods to make sure the default behaviour remains intact.

Comment: Your statement about always calling `super.onBackPressed()` is bad. The default behaviour of `onBackPressed()` (that you will get when you call `super.onBackPressed()`) is to call `finish()` on the current `Activity`. If you want to override this behaviour and do something else (show a dialog or start a different `Activity` or whatever), then you **absolutely, positively do not want to call `super.onBackPressed()`**!

Comment: @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    //my logics;
} this code is written in activity only and I used super.onBackPressed() too in that block